# GridView common button at the bottom is not working

Tags: c#, gridview, c#-3.0

I have a grid view in my front end Aspx page. In which I have three rows and each row is having a textbox and a button. When I have the button in each row and click, I can get the textbox value in my C# string. 
Example:

```
TextBox1  btnSave1
TextBox2  btnSave2 
TextBox3  btnSave3
```

In my C#, my code is this.

```
 protected void btnSave1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
           TextBox TextBox1 = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
           string myString = TextBox1.Text;    
        }
```

But, when I place the button at the bottom of the grid I can't able to get the textbox value in my C# string, instead I am getting empty value.

```
TextBox
TextBox
TextBox

btnSave
```

and my code inside the button click function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grdSettings.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
   TextBox txt = (TextBox)grdSettings.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox");
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `it is not working.`?

Comment: In the first method, when I have button and textbox in the same row, I can get the value in the myString. But, when I have the button at the bottom of the grid and try to get all the text box value, I am getting null for txt.

Comment: What is the ID assigned to the textboxes in the second approach? can you share the GridView code of aspx page?